# htmlagilitypack selectsinglenode returning null

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, selectsinglenode

The problem about that is, it runs correctly just once in a 20 try or so and it is totally random. Couldnt handle the situation... help will be appreciated ^^

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        try
        {
            html = client.DownloadString(url);
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("url'de hata", "Hata", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }

        }

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        HtmlNode foo = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(Xpath);    

        Listbox1.Items.Add(foo.Attributes["href"].Value); //error here 
        currentPage = (foo.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

Comment: Please include an example of HTML where it works, and an example of HTML where it doesn't work. If we don't have that information, what can we do besides offer our sympathies? I doubt very much that the method is haunted. There's a reason for this.

Comment: the problem is it works and it does not works in the same html

Comment: I don't believe you. What have you done to confirm that it is always *exactly* the same HTML, character for character? If your answer is, "I assumed that it should be", that's not the right answer. But show us the HTML so we can see for ourselves.

Comment: That could only really happen if `DownloadString( )` is not always returning the same document. Which is entirely possible.

Comment: how is that exactly possible ?

Comment: @CANARDAAYDIN DownloadString() is returning different text on different calls. That's possible exactly because web servers don't all return the same text for every get request they receive. If every get request to every web server always got the same HTML, nobody would need a web server and nobody would bother loading web pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for nodes is not null. Server may return different response for every request. Server might be returning 20 to 1 element you want. Are you sure the contents are the same? The session may vary depending on the situation. Make sure that successful and unsuccessful contents are equal.